# Form Button Image Mouseover Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form that has nine (yes 9) buttons and I have been requested by the client to provide mouse over action on each one of them. I am very comfortable with standard mouse overs using CSS and background images, but not with how to effectively swap out an image in something like this:

```
<input type="image" src="images/fl-ounces.jpg" name="fluidOunces" alt="" />
```

I have searched far and wide on Google and found one dated (2004) option [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/button2.htm) but I keep thinking there has got to be a better way. I would appreciate some guidance on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to have another image appear on the hover or remove the image on hover?

Comment: Hi Adhip. Yes, that was what I was looking for. Fortunately Sarfraz provided the solution below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<input type="image" src="images/fl-ounces.jpg" name="fluidOunces" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='images/some_image.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/fl-ounces.jpg'" />
```